# Tableview empty on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create a table view to replicate a login function. I have designed the table view and put some default values in the other tabs views.

When I run on the simulator my table view appears empty - but I don't really know or understand why.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you implement the needed `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods to populate the table with data?

Comment: no i didn't - let me search on how i would do that

Comment: Read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS" in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the DataSource in the Interface Builder. Just select the tableView in there and go to the Connections Inspector (last icon on the right side). There on the top is the DataSource, just click the cross to delete it.

[image: Some Image to demonstrate the process]

The Cells have to be static for this (with tableView selected):

[image: Attributes Inspector with tableView selected]

"The difference is with static you dont need to code things because it will be the same, thats what you should have picked since its a login page no need for prototype" - meda

Comment: The tableView is a tableView with static cells right? These are not some dynamic cells aren't they?

Comment: it says prototype cells at the top of the view for some reason - I'm not entirely sure on the difference

Comment: perfect - that was exactly correct - so i need to now go away and understand the difference between static and dynamic prototypes - thanks Benjamin

Comment: The difference is with static you dont need to code things because it will be the same, thats what you should have picked since its a login page no need for prototype

Comment: Exactly meda, sorry for don't explaining that, I add it to the answer.